# Rails CouchDB related models not seing each other

Tags: ruby-on-rails, couchdb

Having this code :

**Models**

paciente.rb

```
class Paciente
  include SimplyStored::Couch
    has_many :consultas
end
```

consulta.rb

```
class Consulta
  include SimplyStored::Couch
    belongs_to :paciente 
end
```

**Controllers**

consultas_controller.rb

```
class ConsultasController < ActionController::Base
  layout "application"
    before_filter :get_paciente
    def get_paciente
        @paciente = Paciente.find(params[:paciente_id])
    end
  def index
    @consultas = @paciente.consultas.all
  end
    def new
        @consulta = @paciente.consultas.new
    end
  def create
    @consulta = Consulta.create(params[:consulta]) 
    if @consulta.save
      redirect_to(@consulta, :notice => 'Consulta was successfully created.')
    else
      render :action => "new"
    end
  end
end
```

**Routes**

routes.rb

```
Example::Application.routes.draw do
    resources :pacientes do
        resources :consultas
    end
end
```

**Error**

I can't list consultas like this.

/pacientes/very long paciente id couchdb style id/consultas

I can see @paciente object exists,(I can inspect it), but i can't reach consultas from there.

Because I get:

```
NameError in ConsultasController#index
uninitialized constant Consultum
```

on this line :

@paciente.consultas.all <-- I am unable to reach consultas

Last couple of days been over and over this, btw I am using the SymplyStored for accessing CouchDb; I have already tried specifying the class name but samee result and the class name is the same name as the relationship.

Thanks in Advance for any clues !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salvador - Rails makes certain assumptions about the pluralization rules, namely that they are in English.  While I am not very familiar with the couchDB api in Rails, it appears from the NameError that Rails is attempting to pluralize `Consultas` -> `Consultum`.

This is a [blog](http://www.viget.com/extend/rails-internationalization-and-tu/) post about another developer's experiences related to non-English model names and ActiveRecord ... chances are, you're running against the same thing in ActiveModel -> SimplyStored::Couch

Comment: yep this was exactly it; I translated all to english.

Comment: I'm glad that solved your problem. My spanish is terrible and it sounds like the blog post author had other troubles working with the Inflector class ... But I suspect improved, localized Inflector behavior is a great area to contribute toward the Rails project and help it into the wider global audience.